# Laravel Redis Queue and supervisor worker - job gets executed multiple times

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, supervisord

I use Redis as a queue driver and dispatch a job that sends notifications to users. The problem is that users get the same notification multiple times.

Laravel 8.0, standard Redis configuration.

Supervisor config:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/artisan queue:work --sleep=0 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
numprocs=10
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/storage/logs/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Job:

```
class NotifySubscribersOfReply implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $thread;
    public $reply

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($thread, $reply)
    {
        $this->thread = $thread;
        $this->reply = $reply;
    }

    /**
     * The unique ID of the job.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function uniqueId()
    {
        return "reply-" . $this->reply->id . "-notification";
    }

    /**
     * The number of seconds after which the job's unique lock will be released.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $uniqueFor = 3600;

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // send notification
    }
}
```

Queue config:

```
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 1800,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],
```

I would be really glad about any hints, thanks!

Comment: You can check if the notification is already sent or not in the `handle()` function. If it's already sent, don't do anything. You need to store the push notifications in database in this case.

Comment: @RifatBinReza true, I could do that. But I wonder if that is necessary?

Comment: From my experience, it is necessary. What if your job takes longer time to complete and then it starts again and after some time the previous one finishes. It's safe to always check when executing the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `retry_after` of redis config in `config/queue.php`. Change it to the maximum value that your job can take for execution. Your job is executing multiple times because your job takes more than `1800` seconds to complete and you have multiple workers running on the horizon.
So, what's happening is one worker picks the job when it's dispatched for the first time then after `1800` seconds another worker picks the same job for execution because it's not completed or deleted from the queue.

Comment: Thanks, but no. My job shouldn't take more than 1 second.

Comment: you can try out adding `public $timeout = {timeout};` in your job. Probably your job completed execution but doesn't deleted from the queues.